# Counter list python 2.7

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, counter

I have list like this:

```
Pasang = [0, 4, 4, 5, 1, 7, 6, 7, 5, 7, 4, 9, 0, 10, 1, 10,...., 23, 9, 23, 7, 23]
```

I count item from that list:

```
satuan = Counter(pasang)
```

then I get :

```
Counter({5: 10, 6: 7, 0: 5, 1: 5, 7: 5, 10: 4, 11: 4, 15: 4,...,14: 1, 21: 1})
```

I want to get key from counter, so i do this:

```
satu = satuan.keys()
```

and I get sorted list like this:

```
[0, 1, 2, 4, 5,...,21, 22, 23]
```

but I need an output like this (not sorted):

```
[5, 6, 0, 1,...,14, 21]
```

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: What do you mean *"not sorted"*? It looks like you **do** want it sorted, but in order of count, in which case see [`Counter.most_common`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common).

Comment: I think he means "Not sorted numerically, but in the same order it shows in the `Counter` object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need:

```
[key for key, freq in c.most_common()]
```

where `c` is the `Counter` instance.

`most_common` will return pairs of keys and frequencies, in decreasing order of frequency. Then you extract the key part using a comprehension.

Comment: So why `Counter.keys` returns a sorted result?

Comment: @Kasra because the keys are integers, which hash to their own values

Comment: @jonrsharpe Just in case anyone gets the wrong idea: that is an implementation detail and will only happen for certain subsets of the integers. Don't rely on it.

Comment: @Veedrac a very good point! It will also depend partly on number and order of the insertion of the keys.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain the order then have a look at the `Counter` object you just created, it has elements sorted w.r.t to the frequency in decreasing order and you can also achieve the same behaviour by sorting the keys on frequency and setting the `reverse` flag to be `True`

```
import collections
Pasang = [0, 4, 4, 5, 1, 7, 6, 7, 5, 7, 4, 9, 0, 10, 1, 10, 23, 9, 23, 7, 23]

a = collections.Counter(Pasang)

keys = sorted(a.keys(), key = lambda x:a[x], reverse = True)
print a
print keys
>>> Counter({7: 4, 4: 3, 23: 3, 0: 2, 1: 2, 5: 2, 9: 2, 10: 2, 6: 1})
>>> [7, 4, 23, 0, 1, 5, 9, 10, 6]
```